# Child nodes are added to a different tree node in a Gxt TreeGrid

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Child nodes in GXT TreeGrid are added to a different tree node even though the nodeId is unique. This issue occurs only when the Tree Node has a same label. Can you please help me in resolving this issue.

The expected result should be like

[image]

But the actual result looks something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two nodes named "USI" - is there any chance that you have made a mistake and the `ModelKeyProvider` in the treestore actually returns the same key for both of them? If you are compiling with assertions enabled it would warn you about this (dev mode and super dev mode), but a normal compilation will strip out these expensive checks.

```
/**
 * Gets a non-null key value that maps to this object. Keys must be consistent and
 * unique for a given model, as a database primary key would be used.
 */
String getKey(T item);
```